# Log4Net not creating a log file, error surrounding the configuration

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, log4net

I'm very new to log4net and eventually I'm messing up something.
I used to have a "failed to find config file" error but it disappeared after hard coding the route in the XmlConfigurator.Configure.
Either I'm stating the route wrongly or the config file is not correct.

Assembly class in my project:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config", Watch = true)]
```

log4net.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">      
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="C:/Log/gateway_%date{yyyyMMdd}.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] – %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Service class:

```
private static readonly log4net.ILog logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Service));
```

Constructor:

```
public Service()
 {            
    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo("SIO.SAPGenerico.log4net.config"));
 }
```

Somewhere in the Service class:

```
logger.Debug("Executing this method");
```

I really can't find the problem.

Comment: Try searching the web and this site for "log4net not writing file" and try a couple of the often-suggested solutions. Enable Log4Net debug logging. Check the permissions. Check the appender names.

Comment: value="C:/Log/gateway_%date{yyyyMMdd}.log". Does your user have enough rights to write in that folder? It also seems a quite complex name, have you tried with a static name for the log first?

Comment: If this is a web project, try Server.MapPath("/SIO.SAPGenerico.log4net.config") if your config file is in the root folder of your web app.

Comment: @CodeCaster gave you the answer - your root logger references an appender called "RollingLogFileAppender" but your actual appender name is "FileAppender"

Comment: **CodeCaster** I tried everything I've come across in those kind of answers before posting this (but I keep searching). **Mario Garcia** I've tried a static name indeed and I have administrator rights. **Oguz Ozgul** It's a WS that has several other projects in the solution. This is the main one.

Comment: @stuartd Thanks for your feedback. I modified the config file and the question. Still no file is being created but it was necessary change.